# JBoss 6.0.0 blank page during war redeploy for 3 seconds

Tags: jboss, delay, war, web-deployment, jboss-web

I have the following problem.
I am using Jboss 6.0.0. I need to daily update the application that runs 24/7 (only WAR file). 
During redeploy the server responds with a blank page (0 bytes). It takes about 3 seconds.

> 13:25:39,001 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment] undeploy,
>   ctxPath=/ 13:25:42,021 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment] deploy,
>   ctxPath=/

This is obviously the most adverse scenario, as users, who  at that moment send the form lose all of the inputed data.

I tried to find a solution setting various configuration options (autoDeploy, unloadDelay, reloadable context attributes) with no success.

Is there something I'm missing or this is normal behavior and the server does not distinguish between redeploy and separate undeploy and deploy operations. It would be ideal if it could distinguish them and if container during the redeploy would queue requests until the next instance of servlet is initialized.

Details of the environment:
JBoss 6.0.0 Final single instance (also tried on Tomcat 7.0.28 - the same effect)
2 x quad core
32 gb ram

WAR:
Context of the web on a virtual host
War file size ~ 20mb
Number of classes ~ 1,5k
Number of files together ~ 7k

I tried to clean up the file and I went down to 700kb (I removed all the img / js / css etc and all lib/), the time shortened to ~ 2 seconds.

Thanks in advance